# Hyperledger Fabric: Broadcast Client xxx is not connected

Tags: sdk, hyperledger-fabric

I use the following two sdk to connect and interact with the local-network created by the extension.

**package.json:**

```
   ...
    "fabric-ca-client": "^2.2.0",
    "fabric-network": "^2.2.0",
   ...
```

What I did first was get the default wallets created here:

`C:\Users\johnny.dacosta\.fabric-vscode\environments\chaincode-env`

I copied it to my workspace and then added the `admin' identity to my wallets with the following function:

```js
    if(this.walletProxy == null){
      //get wallet store
      this.walletProxy = await createWalletProxy(this.configService.get('localnetwork.orgWalletPath'));

      //build new identity
      const certBasePath = joinPathFromCWD(this.configService.get('localnetwork.pathIdentityCert'));
      const keyBasePath = joinPathFromCWD(this.configService.get('localnetwork.pathIdentityKey'));

      const certFilename = getFilesFromPath(certBasePath)[0];
      const keyFilename = getFilesFromPath(keyBasePath)[0];

      if(!certFilename || !keyFilename){
        throw new NotFoundException("certFilename or keyFilename not found");
      }

      const cert = readFileSyncUTF8(`${certBasePath}/${certFilename}`).toString();
      const key = readFileSyncUTF8(`${keyBasePath}/${keyFilename}`).toString();

      //add new identity
      await this.walletProxy.addIdentity(this.configService.get('localnetwork.identity'), {
        credentials: {
            certificate: cert,
            privateKey: key,
        },
        mspId: 'Org1MSP',
        type: 'X.509',
      })
    }
```

```js
        //ENV
        {
      orgWalletPath: ["local-network", "wallets", "Org1", "admin", "user"],
      pathIdentityCert: ["local-network", "wallets", "Org1", "admin", "signcerts"],
      pathIdentityKey: ["local-network", "wallets", "Org1", "admin", "keystore"],
       }
```

[image]

I manage to add the new identity admin:

```
{"credentials":{"certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nLK1NgJxMdYwxQYhGXSV568d+HJROXgb7+vsjd3g=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n","privateKey":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgGRpFEGhHS95y2Fyr\nLk6s6gd0V5D61akQC4RkEC1xYzmhRANCAAR+Q7RTGcp8QqYRKPQbHKNKHyWMVKBc\n4IWog1ejrqGcFvwzldAw0TgckWsnkBrRs9++U2MItem7gwZY3eYV/Wpv\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"},"mspId":"Org1MSP","type":"X.509","version":1}
```

With this identity I can `getState` of my asset:
[image]

But if I try to do `putState` transaction I got this error:

```
2020-08-13T13:14:14.117Z - error: [DiscoveryHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:0 - error on endorsement to peer0.org2.example.com:17097 error Error: Broadcast Client peer0.org2.example.com:17097 grpc://localhost:17097 is not connected
2020-08-13T13:14:14.118Z - error: [DiscoveryHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - error on endorsement to peer0.org1.example.com:17092 error Error: Broadcast Client peer0.org1.example.com:17092 grpc://localhost:17092 is not connected
[Nest] 22548   - 2020-08-13 3:14:14 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'name' of undefined +747178ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at newEndorsementError (C:\DEV\CIB\cib-ledger-api\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\transaction.js:33:36)
    at getResponsePayload (C:\DEV\CIB\cib-ledger-api\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\transaction.js:17:23)
    at Transaction.submit (C:\DEV\CIB\cib-ledger-api\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\transaction.js:214:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

All the peer are up:
[image]

I'm just confused why is not working with `putState` transaction.

I already check my smartcontract is good I can manage to do `putState` operation with the extension:
[image]

### Your Environment

- IBM Blockchain Platform Extension Version: **1.0.36**
- Visual Studio Code version: **1.47.3**
- Environment name and version: Node.js **v10.16.3**, npm **v6.14.7**):
- Operating System and version: **Windows 10 Enterprise v1903**

Comment: This situation is happened because you called a gRPC to peer server but your call failed to hit the server. This situation may happen for many reasons, but for most of the cases the situation is happened due to server down(peer server exit or down due to misconfiguration) or for wrong certificate or your call failed to hit the server due to misconfiguration.

Comment: I check all the peer are up, I'm just confuse why `getState` transactions are ok but when I  run `putState` transactions are failed everytime. As you said maybe due to misconfiguration or wrong certificate... I opened an issue on Github  https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/2600. I update the my question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem...
Just before the transaction I disconnected from the network...

```
  async submitTransaction(transactionConfig: ITransaction2HLF): Promise<void> {
    console.log(transactionConfig.transactionName)
    console.log(...transactionConfig.params)
    await this.buildInstance(transactionConfig);
    this.gateway.disconnect() // <-- ERROR
    await this.contract.submitTransaction(transactionConfig.transactionName, ...transactionConfig.params);
    this.gateway.disconnect()
  }
```

I just removed the line and I downgrade the version `2.2` to `1.4.x` due to the vscode extension ibm blockchain plateform requirements.